# SSRS BIDS 2008 Bubble chart - Bubble size

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, bids

I am using SSRS BIDS 2008 to produce a bubble chart. My chart has around 80 bubbles that are sized on a certain field, however the majority of my bubbles are tiny with 5/6 being massive. I need to somehow adjust the sizing ranges and believe I do this by using BubbleSizeMin and BubbleSizeMax how ever I cannot find these fields anywhere. Can anyone tell me step by step how to get to these fields...? (I have tried right clicking on the bubble in design view, clicking 'Series Properties' and going through all these but cannot see the min/max options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some properties aren't exposed through the dialogs, but are still listed in the BIDS properties window. View -> Properties (or F4) will make this window visible if it isn't currently.

Below is a screen shot of BIDS with these properties shown.

I've run into situations though where setting the minimum bubble size wouldn't make the dots any smaller than the default size, so there seems to be some auto-calculation that can override these.[image: Properties for bubble chart data series]